# call function in controller from view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

i wrote a simple function in controller

```
public string LinkProjectSquareFilter(int squareId)
    {

        return squareId.ToString();
    }
```

how can i call it from view? it say The name 'LinkProjectSquareFilter' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of method should not be in controller at all. If it is only a simple `ToString` call, do it in the view directly.

If it is something more complex, do it in your ViewModel (the type you are passing to your strongly typed view) or create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (e.g. as an extension on `int` type) and call that method from the view directly - but only if it is a simple view related transformation.

If it is a more complex transformation involving any kind of business logic, do that in your controller or in your service layer (used by controller) before passing the data to view.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it static. Then you could call `ControllerNameController.LinkProjectSquareFilter(5);` everywhere in the project as long as you have the required namespaces included (in a viewfile this is done with a `<%@ something` tag at the beginning of the file. I don't remember what that something is thought :-P ...

Comment: the ASP.NET MVC view doesn't usually know anything about the controller. This violates the correct arrangement of dependencies.

Comment: Still, even though it's bad practice and shouldn't be done, it's still possible this way, and that was what he asked for...